# Hide Pdf Toolbar in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

i want to load a pdf file without toolbar.
if i load a pdf file directly using iframe means it doesnt show the toolbar
( working fine with out toolbar). but if i do this in programmatically means it shows the toolbar even i give toolbar=0.
so how to handle this issue.

below code is the programmatic pdf loading. but it shows the toolbar.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] content =FileToByteArray(Server.MapPath("Test.pdf"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Test.pdf#toolbar=0");
    Response.BinaryWrite(content);
    Response.End();
}


/// <summary>
/// Function to get byte array from a file
/// </summary>
/// <param name="_FileName">File name to get byte array</param>
/// <returns>Byte Array</returns>
public byte[] FileToByteArray(string _FileName)
{
    byte[] _Buffer = null;

    try
    {
        // Open file for reading
        System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName,   System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

        // attach filestream to binary reader
        System.IO.BinaryReader _BinaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(_FileStream);

        // get total byte length of the file
        long _TotalBytes = new System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName).Length;

        // read entire file into buffer
        _Buffer = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes((Int32)_TotalBytes);

        // close file reader
        _FileStream.Close();
        _FileStream.Dispose();
        _BinaryReader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception _Exception)
    {
        // Error
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
    }

    return _Buffer;
}


need ur suggestions with examples.
```

**regards**
anbu

Comment: <iframe src="Test.pdf#toolbar=0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe> working fine with out toolbar. but if i do this in programmatically

Comment: Btw, you could replace your FileToByteArray for one line: File.ReadAllBytes(path_to_file);

Answer (score 1):

I am also showing a pdf in an iframe via streaming.

To disable the toolbar and/or navpane I had to put the pdf query parameters AFTER all other query string parameters.

Eg.

```
this.ifm.Attributes["src"] = String.Format("pdfdisplay.aspx?ref={0}#navpane=0", Server.UrlEncode(CurrentServiceHistory.Reference));
```

This removes the left navigation pane, to remove the toolbar you could do the following:

```
this.ifm.Attributes["src"] = String.Format("pdfdisplay.aspx?ref={0}#toolbar=0", Server.UrlEncode(CurrentServiceHistory.Reference));
```

Note: I am setting my iframe (ifm) src property in code behind.